# not able to read data from internal storage in Android Application

Tags: android, internal-storage

I'm using  MOTO G3 phone(Android Device). I wanted to get all PDF files list from my phone. I have followed this tutorial. http://kalisandroid.blogspot.in/2015/01/load-pdf-files.html . I got nothing. But when the same program is run in SONY phone it is displaying the files what was the actual problem. ow to resolve this problem ( i have written Android Manifest permissions also)?

Comment: What OS versions are the 2 phones?  Is one pre-KitKat?

Comment: sony is kitkat(4.4.2) versio ,moto g3 version is Marshmallow

Comment: THey changed legal access to the external card on KitKat.  You can only read certain directories, not the entire disk unless you have root access.

Comment: but nothing is displayed .can i get some code for this??

Answer (score 0):

Call this at runtime:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Do your code here:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

For both version support code read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/6028746)
For additional information on the subject read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)